# Is it possible to get a Game Over in Maniac Mansion by taking too long to rescue Sandy?

Tags: maniac-mansion

In the recent playthrough of Maniac Mansion done by The Game Grumps, Danny suggested that the base game, outside of meltdown timers and such, is on a **timer** that will result in a **Game Over** if it expires.

However, I was under the impression that, while most cutscenes are indeed on timers that count in real-time, and the final cutscene implies an imminent loss, that **it is not possible to lose by waiting too long**, and instead the game will simply "run out" of cutscenes and continue indefinitely afterward.

Which is the truth?

Comment: Well, how long did you leave it just running?

Comment: Would not be the first game with artificial time pressure, making you believe that you need to hurry. See 90% of all modern games.

Comment: I suspect this is a rare case where this actually might be entirely true, but I can't confirm or deny it having never played the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once left the game running for over 5 days (in the background in DosBox) whilst leaving the PC downloading a large set of files.  When I returned to the game I was still in the same room (the room with the plant).

There is nothing to force a game over if you leave the game running.

Answer (score 5):

Not according to [this review](http://www.mobygames.com/game/nes/maniac-mansion/reviews/reviewerId,43595/) at Moby Games

> There is no time limit to defeating this game, unlike many games that were out at the time.

Additionally, the [Ways to lose page](http://www.maniacmansionfan.50webs.com/waystolose.html) at Maniac Mansion Fan makes no mention of running out of time, so I think it's safe to say that there's no time limit to rescuing Sandy.